# Opening an Android Application from a PDF possible?

Tags: android, pdf

I was wondering how to open an android APP from a PDF. I wanted to make a PDF document for kids that would automatically open the application when the child pressed on the apps button on the PDF document. I can generate links in the PDf that will make it open videos and go to web pages, but not that could open an application already installed on the tablet.

Comment: I would expect a PDF viewer to handle links by launching an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` with the link's URL as a `Uri`, if the viewer handles links at all. Note that not all PDF viewers will necessarily handle links.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I've tried file://system/app/org.google.blahblak.apk and others, but they did not work.

Comment: It would be identical to how you open an Android app from a Web browser. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser. You have to modify the app to support starting an activity with a syntax that you can express in a simple URL.

Comment: What if you don't have access to the androidmanifest.xml. What your's trying to do is for the PDF to OPEN an app that was installed from the play store.

Comment: You cannot readily open arbitrary third-party apps via a URL.